# Media Queries - Make images responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a lot of images on my page and are all connected with lines, something like this:

```
$    $
 \  /
   $      ( Assuming $ is an image )
 /  \
$    $
```

When I view this page on my phone, the images and the lines are all scattered.Now using media queries, how can I make the images smaller to fit my phone's screen and WITHOUT the images changing their position. I only want to change their size.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using media query is really simple just use @media and the device range you want. And then inside of it write down the css that you want to apply for that range.

```
img {
   width: 500px; // current width
   height: 500px; // current height
}

@media (max-width:767px){
 img {
   width: 200px; // new width for screen <768px
   height: 200px; // new height for screen <768px
 }
}
```

Also make sure that you add the following code to the head of your html markup.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This single line will make sure that your webpage takes full width of device width and resets any device zooming to 1. And thus will help you set a proper view for your mobile visitors.

Other media query rules:

```
@media (min-width:768px and max-width:1199px){
   // code for device screen between 768 and 1200px
}

@media (min-width:1199px){
   // code for device screen larger than 1199px
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kiran :)..One question, where should I put the @media code?..in the header or body?

Comment: Instead of adding it directly to your html file. Add it to the stylesheet. If style.css is the file where you have written all your css then add it there. Or you can add another file with name say reponsive.css and add it there. Please read here on how to add style to your document: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Answer (score 0):

Yeah Using media queries is simple one 
for example :

@media (min-width:100px) and (max-width: 1024px)

by using in this way change your class or id which is exactly suiting to this mobile view

Second thing is dont use height and width in px rather than use in % then the image also gets shrink based on thw viewport

try it and revert